# I am trying to implement a hover effect using CSS3 Transitions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I am trying to achieve is make a hover effect that when the cursor is hovering the icons the caption will slide from left. Making it seem like it is replacing the icon itself. 
The Image below is what I am currently working on. I can't figure out which part on the CSS is making it not fit inside.

[image: This is the Image]

I am trying to implement this while using Twitter Bootstrap. The hover effect is found [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="container row">
        <!-- Icon row -->
            <div class="view view-fifth span1">
                <img src="images/bahay-dito.png" />
                <div class="mask">
                    <h2>Bahay Dito</h2>
                    <a href="#" class="info">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.view {
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   cursor: default;
}
.view .mask,.view .content {

   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.view h2 {
   color: red;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 15px;
   padding: 10px;
   background: red;
   margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.view p {
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   font-style: italic;
   font-size: 12px;
   position: relative;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 20px 20px;
   text-align: center;
}
.view a.info {
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 7px 14px;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
.view a.info: hover {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

**Styles for the 5th Effect**

```css
.view-fifth img {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.view-fifth .mask {
   background-color: rgba(146,96,91,0.3);
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -o-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-300px);
   transform: translateX(-300px);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.view-fifth h2 {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   color: #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(159, 141, 140, 0.5);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(159, 141, 140, 0.5);
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(159, 141, 140, 0.5);
}
.view-fifth p {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   color: #333;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-fifth:hover .mask {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
   -o-transform: translateX(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
   transform: translateX(0px);
}
.view-fifth:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(300px);
   -o-transform: translateX(300px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(300px);
   transform: translateX(300px);
}
.view-fifth:hover p {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/9DLmb/1/

```
.container {
width:238px;
height:198px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.view {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
cursor: default;
}
.view .mask, .view .content {
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
.view h2 {
color: red;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 10px;
background: red;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.view p {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 12px;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px 20px 20px;
text-align: center;
}
.view a.info {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 7px 14px;
background: #000;
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
.view a.info: hover {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
.view-fifth img {
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.view-fifth .mask {
background-color: rgba(146, 96, 91, 0.3);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
-moz-transform: translateX(-300px);
-o-transform: translateX(-300px);
-ms-transform: translateX(-300px);
transform: translateX(-300px);
-ms-filter:"progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
width:238px;
height:203px;
}
.view-fifth h2 {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
color: #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(159, 141, 140, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(159, 141, 140, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(159, 141, 140, 0.5);
}
.view-fifth p {
-ms-filter:"progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
color: #333;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-fifth:hover .mask {
-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
-moz-transform: translateX(0px);
-o-transform: translateX(0px);
-ms-transform: translateX(0px);
transform: translateX(0px);
}
.view-fifth:hover img {
-webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
-moz-transform: translateX(300px);
-o-transform: translateX(300px);
-ms-transform: translateX(300px);
transform: translateX(300px);
}
.view-fifth:hover p {
-ms-filter:"progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
}
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @San I have updated and closed the div tag, I tried your answer but since the size of the icon itself is smaller, it still appeared cropped.

What did was 

    .mask{width:60px;height:60px;}
But thank you anyway, your answer gave me insight on what to do next.